# Nonetype object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, attributes, cursor

I am retrieving the last id from mssql and trying to incrementing it and storing the fie name with the id.. But I am getting "Attribute error : Nonetype object has no attribute 'id'"..The code and the error goes here :

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog 
import shutil    
import pyodbc    
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=PAVAN;DATABASE=video;Trusted_Connection=yes;")   
cursor = cnxn.cursor()  
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 id  FROM files ORDER BY id DESC ")

while 1:   
    row = cursor.fetchone()  
    if not row:   
        break   
    print row.id    
cnxn.close()    
middle = Tkinter.Tk()

def withdraw():    
   dirname = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=middle,initialdir="H:/",title='Please 
select a file')    
   a="H:python(test)\py_"+row.id+".mp4"    
   b=shutil.copyfile(dirname,a)

   if b!="":    
       print "Successfully Copied"    
   else:    
       print "Could not be copied"

B = Tkinter.Button(middle, text ="UPLOAD", command = withdraw)    
middle.geometry("450x300+100+100")    
middle.configure(background="black")    
B.pack() 
middle.mainloop()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
      return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\upload.py", line 20, in withdraw
    a="H:python(test)\py_"+row.id+".mp4"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when the you try to get **id** Attribute from object which is of None type ,
Here is a case :

```
>> a = None
>> a.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

So it might be the case object **row** is of None type , and you are trying to print row.id

You may check for the type of row using :

```
type(**row**)
```

With Regards
Deepak